# Laravel 5 routes of Modules can't working correct when use authentication middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm create folder modules in folder app.
I'm config complete.

- Module directory structure:
  [Module directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hom27.png)

**module.php**

```
return  [
    'modules' => [
        'Product',
    ]
];
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'products', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Product\Controllers'], function() {
//  Route::get('/categories', ['as' => 'categories.index', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@index']);
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'products.index', 'uses' => 'ProductController@index']);
});
```

**ProducController.php**

```
namespace App\Modules\Product\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Product::product');
    }
}
```

But when go to http://xxxxxxx.dev/products page redirect to Welcome page.
If i remove **'middleware' => 'auth'** routes.php working correct.

Please help me!

Comment: I fixed it. In file route change 'middleware' => 'auth' to 'middleware' => 'web'.  In file ProductController add _public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware('auth');
 }_